# sleep in android doesn't work

Tags: android, sleep

Well I just want to press a button and a countdown appears in it however when I press the button the program stops and finally shows the number 1 but doesn't show 3 or 2.

```
btnTurno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnTurno.setText("3");
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        btnTurno.setText("2");
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        btnTurno.setText("1");
    }
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you were looking for `Thread.sleep(1000)`, but this is NOT recommended. As you will sleep the main thread.

Comment: sleep in android **does** work. you are just not using it correctly.

Comment: basically, it can't sleep **and** draw at the same time, same as anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Sleep should be called as Thread.sleep(x);

But on the other hand , sleep is NOT recommended since it will block the user interaction with the application.

If you want to make a countdown ( as it looks like what you are doing ), you should look at this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: "Sleep should be called as Thread.sleep(x)" -- on Android, `SystemClock.sleep()` is perfectly fine, at least anywhere that `Thread.sleep()` would be fine. IOW, while the use of `sleep()` in the question is inappropriate, that's not because it was called on `SystemClock` and not `Thread`.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! I did not know the SystemClock ! Although i did not say the problem was the sleep itself :)

Comment: As far as I know SystemClock.sleep() does not require catching interrupted exception, and thats whole difference

Answer (score 1):

onClick is being executed in single handler message on GUI thread, so each time you change text, it overwrites previous value, so system is not able to redraw view.

Also you should not call sleep() on main gui thread, that will cause ANR - application is notresponding

Answer (score 1):

Setting the text and drawing the text are separate operations that both happen on the same thread.  You're setting the text three times before the framework gets the chance to draw anything, so all you see is the last change.

For this to work, you'd need to do your text updates and sleeps on a separate thread.  However, you can't make UI calls directly on a different thread, so you need to post your messages.

One approach would be to create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), and use your code above but call `publishProgress()` where you're currently calling `setText()`.  The `publishProgress()` call in the async thread results in `onProgressUpdate()` running in the UI thread; from there, you can call `setText()` to update the UI.

**Edit:** the `CountDownTimer` approach mentioned in a different answer is better.